# What is the "Isolated Image" attribute in a PE?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, portable-executable

If i view a portable executable's innards, inside the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` section there is the `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_ISOLATION` field, which as Microsoft mentions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx#IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_ISOLATION) it means that: "The image is isolation aware, but should not be isolated.". However, I don't understand what is meant, or implied here and can't find more information on this. This option also exists as a Visual Studio option and it is enabled by default (VS 2015 C++) when one creates a Win32 application project. I'd like to know what it does to code generation before i enable it.

If someone knows, please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It controls whether the Windows loader looks for a [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa375632) when loading the process:

> **`/ALLOWISOLATION`** causes the operating system to do manifest lookups and loads.
>
> **`/ALLOWISOLATION`** is the default.
>
> **`/ALLOWISOLATION:NO`** indicates that executables are loaded as if there were no manifest, and causes EDITBIN Reference to set the `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_ISOLATION` bit in the optional header's `DllCharacteristics` field.
>   When isolation is disabled for an executable, the Windows loader doesn't try to find an application manifest for the newly created process. The new process doesn't have a default activation context, even if there is a manifest in the executable itself or if there is a manifest that has the name `executable-name.exe.manifest`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69xzf91x.aspx